# How to optimize the search loop in text groups of words that can be composed from word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I took the words out of the text, which contains about 100000 unique words, and made a dictionary out of them.

```
d=dict.fromkeys(lines)
for i in d:
  d[i]=dict(Counter(i).items())
```

Then to find words that can be composed of a word, I run a loop, which unfortunately only works on a small amount of data

```
s={}  
for w1 in d:
  for w2 in d:
    if w1!=w2 and set(w2).issubset(set(w1)) and len(w2)<=len(w1):
      for k in d[w2].keys():
        if d[w2][k]>d[w1][k]:
          w=None
          break
        else:
          w=w2
      if w!=None:
        if w1 in s:
          s[w1].append(w)
        else:
          s[w1]=[w]
```

How to avoid a double 'for'? Is there a method to compare keys without making second dict?

Comment: I don't quite follow what the intended task is. Could you show a small example of the original words and the desired corresponding output?

Comment: for example (small text), lines=['generator','reagent','retreat','rotten'] 
and output should be 'generator':'reagent'

Comment: Ok wait, you want to find words that are composed of words in a text, or am I understanding this completely wrong?

Comment: So, all pairs where one word can be made using the letters from another (as though they were Scrabble tiles)?

Comment: Yes, you right. But I want to find words in text that are composed of each word in a text, which contains 90000+ words

Comment: @Iris, why are you complicating it by using keys? I feel like just using one dictionary, the second one you made, making two loops for the dictionary and checking it with something like if word1 != word2 and word1 in word2:

Comment: @Canbach, even without second dict I still make two loops. Maybe you right and I'm complicating, but I don't know how check each word in other way

Comment: @Iris, Hi I am interested to know what your project overall aim is, is it for a game for example. I am working on a project that involves a large text file of English words, the aim for me is to produce a module that can generate random sentences but I am still early in this project, similar to you in access and iteration of the database.

Comment: @Iris Just want to add that List's are native to python, I am using a text file with 65000 words and I read them straight into a python list, so if it's the speed you want, it could be a faster approach.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, if you want every combination of N items in a collection, you probably want to reach for [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations).

```py
import itertools

for w1, w2 in itertools.combinations(d.keys(), 2):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried it before, but it was useful only for small texts and for larger text it too slow.

Comment: @Iris It's only slower if you made a list out of the combinations first and then iterated over that.